# Why is my 17.10 system crashing?

Tags: crash

Up until a few days ago, my PC was stable.  Last couple days, when I came in the morning, the system had rebooted, the screen was at a login.

I'm running 17.10, that should be up-to-date, and did leave the system with programs such as Chrome and Thunderbird running when I left.  The machine is a fairly run-of-the-mill AMD chip on an Asrock mb.  I looked in /var/log/syslog but nothing jumped off the page saying "HERE'S WHAT'S WRONG", but then I'm not sure what I should be seeing.

If someone could first give me a pointer of what I should look at, and/or what I need to do to figure out what's happening, that'd be great.  Note: I did look at what seemed to be similar questions to this, but none seemed to apply.

Comment: What's the output of `dmesg` after a crash?

Comment: The output of dmesg way exceeds a comment here, or even what I can put in by editting my original post.  How do I get that much data here?  Or is there something to look for?

Comment: First, how do you know the system is crashing, and that you didn't accidentally tell it to reboot after updates?

Comment: It wasn't doing updates.  When I walked away it had things running.  When I came back in the morning, it had the login screen (this is in my house, so I don't lock) and after logging in, conky took a few seconds to start and I had to run my script to mount a couple network drives... just like it had re-booted.  IF it did apply update, (they are set to automatic) and it may have, it gave me no indication that it was going to pull the plug on running programs and reboot.  ...but then again, that's part of why I asked the question, I don't know why it booted, and I don't know how to find out why.